# Calculating the negative force with $F_{\mu}=N_{\mu}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction

If a 300kg vehicle is decelerating from $10\,\text m/\text s$ to $5\,\text m/\text s$ during 1000 meters, how can I calculate the negative force (the decelerating force)? According to this equation $F_{\mu}=N_{\mu}$ we can solve $$F=\frac{N_{\mu}}{\mu}=N$$ and it means that $$F=N=m\cdot g=300\,\text{kg} \cdot 9.81\,\text m/\text s^2$$ I'm unsure if this really is correct, because I haven't used anything else than only the mass when there is also distance and velocity. Is there something I'm missing or is my logic right?

Comment: Where did you find those equations?

Comment: Use $v^2=u^2+2as$. This problem has nothing to do with $g$.

Comment: @J.G. This equation will be applicable if the acceleration is constant. OP has not mentioned the type of motion here.

Comment: @Mechanic7 Very true. In the general case, the question as posed can't be answered; we'd have to settle for a distance-averaged deceleration.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have misunderstood the question.
What you have calculated by $F=mg$ (with $g=9.81\text{ m/s}^2$)
is just the vertical weight force of the vehicle.
But the question is not about friction or *vertical* force.
Instead the question describes the *horizontal* movement of a vehicle.

You can set up the kinematic equations for position $x(t)$ and
velocity $v_x(t)$ with a constant negative acceleration $a$.
$$x(t)=x(0)+v_x(0)t+\frac {1}{2}at^2$$
$$v_x(t)=v_x(0)+at$$
You know position and velocity at beginning time ($t=0$):
$x(0)=0$, and $v_x(0)=10 \text{ m/s}$.

You also know position and velocity at end time ($t=t_\text{end}$):
$x(t_\text{end})=1000\text{ m}$, and $v_x(t_\text{end})=5\text{ m/s}$.

Doing so you have two equations with two unknowns ($t_\text{end}$ and the acceleration $a$).
Do the math and find these unknowns.
After having found the acceleration $a$ you calculate the
corresponding force which causes this acceleration.

Comment: I can't still figure out how those two equations would look like.

Comment: @JonathanGarcia see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume acceleration is constant you can use the following.

$v^2 = v_o^2 + 2a(\Delta S)$, to calculate $a$, as J.G. indicated.

$v= v_o + aT$, to calculate $T$.

Then,

$MV_o + FT = MV$, to calculate $F$.

Comment: Why do you need the time? It is not required in the question.

Comment: To calculate the force using change in momentum. There may be other ways to calculate force, this is just my solution.

Comment: You know the mass and you found the acceleration. And I suppose you know Newton's second law.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to utilize momentum. If this is a homework problem and the student knew the chapter, then once the Acceleration is obtained they would realize the Force could be calculated. If my solution is copied the correct answer will be achieved (by alternate means), but the teacher would realize the student needed more assistance with Newton's laws.